# Ice Cream Sandwich Android Tabs Style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-tabhost, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm looking for a way to give style to my app tabs Android 4 similar to the image and that each tab has its own activity class.

[image]

Comment: Are you using ActionBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a note, a TabHost is a native Android piece, so it will be rendered differently per phone (unless you create the tab images).

ActionBarSherlock's bar will provide an ICS style navbar experience to pre-4.0 devices in a more dynamic manner: http://actionbarsherlock.com/. It is also a very nice library for other actionbar related items if you want to support earlier targets.

Once you have the tab bars in, per-tab fragments are probably the easiest way to go: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/

Comment: I concur with this. You can also use the Action Bar itself, in which case the theme attributes you'll need to worry about are `actionBarTabStyle` and `actionBarTabBarStyle`. If you want just the tabs on top, you would call `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` on the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)

Use tabHost's method addTab() to set an image and linked activity for each tab like this (in your .java file's onCreate method)

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("First", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1pic)).setContent(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Second", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2pic)).setContent(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)));

/* etc */

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```